# Post in flask does not render new template

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Let's say I have this setup

Why after clicking "arrToPython" button flask does not redirect me to "query_result.html"? And more importantly, how can I make it to do so?

I tried creating separate route like and using flask's "redirect" method, but it did not work for me either :(
test.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, url_for
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect, Response


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def savingImage():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('test.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('query_result.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Where **test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> <body>
    <input id="arrToPython" type=button value="arrToPython" href="result" onclick = "arrToPython()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function arrToPython(){
        var arr = ['one', 'two']
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/',
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        }).done(function(){
            console.log('sent');
        })
    }

    </script> </body> </html>
```

And **query_result.html**

```
<br> Hola amigo!</br>
```

Comment: If you want to be redirected, why are you using Ajax?

Comment: Using ajax, the page wont get redirected. Your Flask app is redirecting but the browser will not redirect until redirected by the user. This is due to browser, not your flask app.